# Facebook JSON Parser (Android) not returning all photos from album

Tags: android, facebook, json, parsing

I'm trying to write an app that retrieves all the photos from albums of a certain group page. I'm using the Facebook SDK to retrieve JSON data. Getting a list of albums works but the problem is getting photos. After the user selects an album from the spinner list, it's supposed to use the Facebook SDK to retrieve the JSON data for that album, using the album id, and then get all the "source" fields from this data in order to get links to the pictures. Unfortunately, this doesn't work properly. When I load Wall Photos, for example, I only get 1 picture. When I load some other albums, I get no pictures. Only is it a rare occurrence that I get 3 pictures.

Here's a link to my project folder
http://www.shadownet.net76.net/safe/bm.zip